# Using converted tracks in iTunes applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I have a script that iterates through tracks in a playlist. If they are already mp3 it adds them to my iPod (`duplicate currentTrack to ipod_lib`) and removes them from the playlist - this part works fine. If they are lossless however, I want to convert them to mp3 and add them to my iPod instead of add the lossless files themselves since they are too large. The line `duplicate convertedTrack to ipod_lib` throws the following error...

*error "iTunes got an error: Can’t set library playlist id 270897 of source id 235166 to {file track id 322339 of library playlist id 38702 of source id 68}." number -10006 from library playlist id 270897 of source id 235166*

the `locateiPods` code is pulled from a script on http://dougscripts.com/

Really not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

```
on locateiPods()
    set the volumes_directory to "/Volumes/" as POSIX file as alias
    set the volume_names to list folder volumes_directory without invisibles
    set mounted_iPods to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of volume_names
        try
            set this_name to item i of volume_names
            set this_disk to ("/Volumes/" & this_name & "/") as POSIX file as alias
            set these_items to list folder this_disk
            if "iPod_Control" is in these_items then
                set the end of the mounted_iPods to this_disk
            end if
        end try
    end repeat

    -- check for iPod count
    if the mounted_iPods is {} then
    --
        try
            display dialog "iPod is not mounted." buttons {"Cancel"} with icon 0 giving up after 15
        on error
            error number -128
        end try

    else if the (count of the mounted_iPods) is greater than 1 then
        -- choose iPod
        set the ipod_names to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of the mounted_iPods
            set this_iPod to item i of the mounted_iPods
            tell application "Finder"
                set the end of the ipod_names to the name of this_iPod
            end tell
        end repeat
        tell application "iTunes"
            activate
            set this_name to (choose from list ipod_names with prompt "Pick the iPod to use:") as string
        end tell
        if this_name is "false" then error number -128
            repeat with i from 1 to the count of the ipod_names
                if item i of the ipod_names is this_name then
                    set this_iPod to item i of the mounted_iPods
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
    else
        set this_iPod to item 1 of the mounted_iPods
    end if
    return this_iPod
end locateiPods

tell application "iTunes"
    set allTracks to every track in user playlist "TEST"
    set the_iPod to my locateiPods() -- this is a path
    set the_iPod_name to text 1 thru -2 of (the_iPod as string)
    set ipod_src to some source whose name is the_iPod_name
    set ipod_lib to library playlist 1 of ipod_src

    repeat with i from 1 to count of allTracks
        set currentTrack to item i of allTracks
        set fileType to kind of currentTrack as string
        if fileType is "MPEG audio file" then
            duplicate currentTrack to ipod_lib
            tell playlist "TEST" to delete contents of currentTrack
        end if
        if fileType is "Apple Lossless audio file" then
            set convertedTrack to convert currentTrack
            duplicate convertedTrack to ipod_lib
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

It seems doing the following makes it work, which suggests that `convertedTrack` is not of type `track`???

```
set convertedTrack to convert currentTrack
repeat with theTrack in convertedTrack
    duplicate theTrack to ipod_lib
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always used "convert" for list of tracks and then result is list of tracks. by the way it is much faster to convert list of tracks instead of doing loop to convert each track. May be you should do first a select of all tracks whose kind is lossless.

About convert, also keep in mind that convert does the conversion to the format set in your iTunes preferences. Then your scrip will depend of these preferences. I suggest, to be more safe, to save current preference, set the convert mode to format you want MP3, and then reset preferences to what they were before. You can use bellow script:

```
-- get & save current encoder
tell application "iTunes" to set Encoder_Base to name of current encoder

-- change encoder to MP3
tell application "iTunes" to set current encoder to (get first encoder whose name contains "MP3")
```

Also, may be you can optimise your iPod subroutine using Source method instead of looking for volumes mounted. iTunes kind of source provides an efficient way:

```
-- kind of source could be : library, iPod, audio CD, MP3 CD, radio tuner, shared library, iTunes Store
tell application "iTunes"
set myList to every source whose kind is iPod
if myList is {} then
    display alert "no ipod connected"
    return
else -- I assume if one iPod found, there is only 1 connected !!
    set SourceName to name of first item of myList
    set SourceID to id of first item of myList
end if
end tell
```

I hope it helps.